# simple neural network in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I've spent the last few days learning the beginnings of how to implement a simple neural network. I've gone through chapters 1 and 2 of this [book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) and have tried to write my own NN with referrals to the code given when I had some trouble.

I am working with the mnist dataset. At the bottom of my question I have listed the equations that I am using from the book. The following are the what I expect to be the dimensions of the matrices used for the calculations based on the network structure:

number of neurons in each layers 1, 2 and 3:
$$n = 784, 16, 10$$
weight matrices in layer 2 and 3:
$$w = [16, 784], [10, 16]$$
biases for layers 2 and 3:
$$b = [16, 1], [10, 1]$$
weighted sum inputs to layers 2 and 3:
$$z = [16, 1], [10, 1]$$
gradient vectors for weights:
$$\nabla w = [16, 784], [10, 16]$$
gradient vectors for biases:
$$\nabla b = [16, 1], [10, 1]$$

One curiosity I have from the book is that the inputs to the network are considered activations in the code but this is not mentioned anywhere in it so far as I could find. i.e. x = activations[0].
Based on this the sizes for the activation output arrays for layers 1, 2 and 3 would be: $$a = [784, 1], [16, 1], [10, 1]$$

If my matrix dimensions are correct and the equations I am using provided at the bottom are correct, well obviously I should get the right results.
What I'm hoping someone can do for me is point out where I am making mistakes with the matrix operations used for backpropagation equations.

```
import random
import numpy as np


class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputs, targets, hidden, n_outputs, learning_rate, epochs, batch_size):

        # training and testing data
        self.training_inputs = inputs  # network inputs
        self.targets = targets  # target outputs for the training data
        self.n_data = len(self.training_inputs)  # number of training data

        # network structure
        self.n_inputs = len(self.training_inputs[0])  # number of input nodes
        self.hidden_layers = hidden  # list containing the number of neurons in each hidden layer. Layer number is the index.
        self.n_outputs = n_outputs  # number of outputs in the final layer
        n_nuerons = [[self.n_inputs], self.hidden_layers, [self.n_outputs]]
        self.layers = [x for s in n_nuerons for x in s]  # list of the number of neurons in each layer. Layer number is the index
        self.n_layers = len(self.layers)  # number of layers in the network

        # hyperparameters
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batch_size = batch_size  # batching is not implemented yet.. using online learning

        # initialise matrices
        self.b, self.z = [], []
        for neurons in self.layers[1:]:  # loop through all layers except the input network layer
            self.b.append(np.random.randn(neurons))  # biases
            self.z.append(np.zeros(neurons))  # layer weighted sum inputs
        self.a = [np.zeros(n) for n in self.layers]  # activation outputs - including inputs to network as activation outputs for layer 0
        self.w = [np.random.rand(self.layers[i + 1], self.layers[i]) - 0.5 for i in range(self.n_layers - 1)]  # weights

        self.train()

    def train(self):
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            random.shuffle(self.training_inputs)
            sum_error = 0
            for index in range(self.n_data):
                # forward pass
                x = self.training_inputs[index]
                self.a[0] = x
                outputs = self.feedforward(x)
                sum_error += sum(self.cost(outputs, index))
                # backward pass
                dw, db = self.backpropagation(index)
                self.update_weights(dw, db)
            print('>epoch=%d, error=%.3f' % (epoch, sum_error))

    def feedforward(self, output):
        for layer in range(self.n_layers - 1):
            self.z[layer] = np.dot(self.w[layer], self.a[layer]) + self.b[layer]  # layer inputs
            self.a[layer + 1] = self.sigmoid(self.z[layer])  # output activations
        return self.a[-1]

    def backpropagation(self, index):
        # initialise gradient matrices
        dw = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.w]
        db = [np.zeros(n) for n in self.layers[1:]]

        # loop backwards through network layers
        for i in reversed(range(1, self.n_layers)):
            if i == self.n_layers - 1:
                # output layer
                db[-1] = (self.a[-1] - self.targets[index]) * self.sp(self.z[-1])
                dw[-1] = np.dot(np.asmatrix(db[-1]), np.asmatrix(self.a[-2]).transpose())
            else:
                # all other layers
                # NOTE: to compute the weight gradient vector for hidden layer 1 the inputs to the network are used as activation outputs
                db[i - 1] = np.multiply(np.dot(np.transpose(self.w[i]), db[i]), self.sp(self.z[i - 1]))
                dw[i - 1] = np.dot(np.asmatrix(db[i - 1]), np.asmatrix(self.a[i - 2]).transpose())

        return dw, db

    def update_weights(self, dw, db):
        self.w = np.array([w - self.learning_rate * nw for w, nw in zip(self.w, dw)])
        self.b = np.array([b - self.learning_rate * nb for b, nb in zip(self.b, db)])

    def cost(self, outputs, index):
        return (self.targets[index] - outputs) ** 2

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid(z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    @staticmethod
    def sp(z):
        return z * (1.0 - z)


# Program driver
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.load('mnist.npz')
    (training_images, test_images) = data['x_train'], data['x_test']
    (training_labels, test_labels) = data['y_train'], data['y_test']
    n_outputs = 10
    training_inputs = np.array([data.flatten() / 255 for data in training_images])
    training_targets = []
    for i in range(len(training_labels)):
        training_targets.append([1 if training_labels[i] == x else 0 for x in range(n_outputs)])
    nn = nn.NeuralNetwork(training_inputs, np.array(training_targets), [16], n_outputs, learning_rate=0.1, epochs=10, batch_size=100)
```

For reference these are the equations I am using for the backpropagation taken more or less directly from the book.

The output errors are calculated using the gradient of the cost function wrt the output activations and the slope of the activation function evaluated at the inputs to the output layer:
$$\delta^L = \nabla_aC\odot\sigma'({z^L)}$$

The errors in all other layers are found by backpropagating the error in the *next* layer through the weights and taking the product of this result with the slope of the activation function evaluated at the inputs to the layer.

$$\delta^l = (w^{l+1})^T\delta^{l+1}\odot\sigma'({z^l)} = (a^L-y)\odot \sigma'(z^L)$$

The error for a given layer calculated using the above equations is the partial derivative of the cost function wrt the biases. Therefore the biases need to be changed by this amount.

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial b_j^l}=\delta_j^{l}$$

The equation used to find the change in weight *w* required to reduce cost function is:
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial w_{jk}^l}=a^{l-1}_k\delta_j^l$$

Finally the equations that will be used to update the weights and bias matrices are:
$$w^l \rightarrow w^l-\eta \delta^{l} (a^{l-1})^T$$
$$b^l \rightarrow b^l-\eta \delta^{l}$$

The code is on [github](https://github.com/ad-1/MachineLearning/tree/master/neural_network) with the mnist included for anyone who may need it. Any comments, corrections, criticisms, all and everything welcome with the aim of learning.. Thanks!